# Should I Add images Subdomain To Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, subdomain, google-image-search

My website:

```
example.com
```

My images subdomain:

```
images.example.com
```

I added `images.example.com` to search console a few years ago, because I had read that subdomains should be added to search console.

Now When I view the performance section of this subdomain in search console, there are no hits.

Was it a wrong or unnecessary action to add this images subdomain?

Comment: Is your page actually fetching anything from there ?  Are you sure its not blocked by robots.txt ?

Comment: yes, all my images are in that subfolder. Also when I visit images.google.com I can see some of my images are indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Can't give a definitive answer without more information, but you probably have indexing issues on your subdomain. The subdomain may not be indexable by Google depending on the setup on the subdomain. Check htaccess and robots.txt for Disallows.

There is a possibility that none of your images are getting served because they aren't relevant to searches, but I think the first answer is more likely.